# How to mask an view with an black-white image?

Tags: iphone

I've heard that it's possible to mask views with black/white images, where black means fully transparent and white means view is visible. The big difference to clipsToBounds is that the view could be clipped in funny shapes like circles or stars. How could I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CGImageRef maskRef = <some cgimage>; 
CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef), CGImageGetHeight(maskRef), CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef), CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef), CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, YES);
CGContextClipToMask(context, maskRect, mask);
CGImageRelease(mask);
```

Answer (score 4):

Look at a function

```
void CGContextClipToMask (
   CGContextRef c,
   CGRect rect,
   CGImageRef mask
);
```

If I understood correctly it does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
 CGImageRef maskImage = <Black-White Image>
 const CGFloat components[6] = {0,0,0,0,0,0}; // mask black color
 CGImageRef mask = CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(maskImage, components);
 CGContextClipToMask(ctx, mask)
// draw images will be masked
```